# Qt - How to compile a particular plugin/component

Tags: c++, windows, qt, compilation, logic

I am using Qt 4.7.2. I made one project which requires mp3 support. So I added the phonon support to it . When I compiled it statically It showed some linking errors like the below

```
Element.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public:   
class Phonon::MediaSource __thiscall Phonon::MediaObject::currentSource(void)const " 
(__imp_?currentSource@MediaObject@Phonon@@QBE?AVMediaSource@2@XZ) referenced in function 
"public: void __thiscall Element::save(void)" (?save@Element@@QAEXXZ)


MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)  
public: class Phonon::MediaSource __thiscall  
Phonon::MediaObject::currentSource(void)const " (__imp_? 
currentSource@MediaObject@Phonon@@QBE?AVMediaSource@2@XZ)
```

I didn't give -no-phonon option when I compiled the library. But I suspect that phonon won't be compiled statically by default. Is there any way to compile phonon alone in static manner, and link that library(or copy paste that dll) in my project?

**EDIT:**
   May be a belated edit. I left the project files somewhere. I have to dig them in my free time. But, it may help the others . This is from the link stated by 'Lukasz Czerwinski'. I think this is the reason.

```
General rule #4: Phonon can't be compiled statically into your application and in 

general Phonon will not work for statically built apps. Link your Phonon-based app 

dynamically."
```

Comment: if you are on windows and use VS, look for solution files created by configure in phonon directory. if they exist, you may just run nmake from that dir.

Comment: @Raiv I am doing it on qt-creator using mingw

Comment: then try to call qmake from phonon dir

Comment: No, you are NOT using mingw. The error messages you cited are from the MS linker. Also, can you post your .pro file?

Comment: Phonon (and its plugins-backends) simply do not support static compilation.

Comment: @Nikita Then what is the solution for Phonon support?

Comment: @Raiv your solution worked. But I didn't check that dll yet.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding: 
`LIBS += -lphonon` to .pro file worked fine.

If this didn't help, take a look at: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_get_Phonon_working and check that you have all files that are stated there.

Comment: That's good that my link appears to be helpful. Why not to vote up my answer? :)
@prabhakaran

Comment: Please check the question . Your solution is solving the problem, but not the direct answer . Actually "Raiv's" first comment is the perfect answer for this question. I am expecting much more clear generalized answer because the question is a generalized question.